# Two Dimensional Scroll in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

Am a newbie to xamarin.forms and am trying to create a own scrollviewer as of in Windows with two dimensional scroll. I have worked with Android and i have achieved the same behavior by deriving it from FrameLayout and initializing a scroller into it with all the action_down , up events it came up well.

But now the real question is i don't find anything similar to Android (in xamarin.forms default layouts and controls) and it's really hard for me to come up with a rough idea.

The scenario is loading a dozens of TextBlocks inside the view , like that of grid layout and it should scroll vertical and horizontal and also diagonally.

Whether i should approach it with renderer by creating a separate scroll for each platforms or is possible in xamarin.forms if possible can you gimme a hint for it.

Thanks in advance.

Dinesh kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without custom renderers. Except in iOS, the behavior works as expected there. This, however, does not currently work with Windows Phone.

This is an example class I cooked up. Just pass something into the text attribute that contains newline characters. I would recommend something from http://i-tools.org/lorem and just output plain text, 1 sentence per line, 1 line per paragraph, and end each line with '\n' if you're stuck for ideas.

```
public class BothDirectionsScrollPage : ContentPage
{
    public BothDirectionsScrollPage(string title, string text)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        var count = 0;
        var splittext = text.Split('\n');
        var stack = new StackLayout();
        foreach (var line in splittext)
        {
            var label = new Label
            {
                Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Medium),
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap,
                FormattedText = new FormattedString()
                {
                    Spans = {new Span {Text = line}}
                }
            };
            stack.Children.Add(label);
            count++;
        }
        var scroll = new ScrollView
        {
            Padding = 0,
            WidthRequest = 500,
            Content = stack,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        Content = new ScrollView()
        {
            Content = scroll,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,

        };
    }
}
```

This is the custom renderer you will need to include in your Android project.

```
using System;
using Android.Views;
using Your.Namespace.Droid.Renderers
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(CustomScrollViewRenderer))]

namespace Your.Namespace.Droid.Renderers
{
        /// <summary>
    /// Used to allow horizontal and vertical scroll views. Xamarin.Android does not bubble the     events down correctly.
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {

        private float StartX, StartY;
        private int IsHorizontal = -1;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (((ScrollView) e.NewElement).Orientation == ScrollOrientation.Horizontal) IsHorizontal = 1;

        }

        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    StartX = e.RawX;
                    StartY = e.RawY;
                    this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    if (IsHorizontal*Math.Abs(StartX - e.RawX) < IsHorizontal*Math.Abs(StartY - e.RawY))
                        this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }

            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Credit to Xavyer at http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20834/horizontal-scrollview-within-vertical-scrollview